# Highstock title setting via options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have used the same chart base to show different measurement quantities in same chart based to quantity selection. I have used Highcharts setOptions function to set the quantity specific setup, for example chart title.

Now I have faced the situation that I needs to change to the Highstock chart the title setting via setOptions function doesn't work.

Is this bug or wanted feature?

Comment: Check this discussion  https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2944 .It will help. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qomp2pqh/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use `setOptions` to change chart title? You can set all other options with `setOptions` function and update specific title with `chart.update` or `chart.setTitle`.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#setTitle
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#update

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ltjq9bbm/.